# Add Spaces in edit text when user types.Format of Australian ABN number

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi I need spaces after 2nd,6th and 10th character in edit text String as user type. For example if user types 51824753553 in edit text so on text change the edit text should display values as 51 824 753 553 .I searched for good solutions to do this but ended up with this solution which I guess is the only way.

```
 mBinding?.txtAbncode?.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {

          override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
              var inputlength = mBinding?.txtAbncode?.text.toString().length
              if (count <= inputlength && (inputlength == 2 || inputlength == 6 || inputlength == 10)){
                  mBinding?.txtAbncode?.setText(mBinding?.txtAbncode?.text.toString()+" ")
                  var pos = mBinding?.txtAbncode?.text!!.length
                  mBinding?.txtAbncode?.setSelection(pos)
              }
              else if(count >= inputlength &&(inputlength == 3 ||
                          inputlength == 7 || inputlength == 11)){
                  mBinding?.txtAbncode?.setText(mBinding?.txtAbncode?.text.toString().substring(0,mBinding?.txtAbncode?.text.toString().length-1))
                  var pos = mBinding?.txtAbncode?.text?.length
                  mBinding?.txtAbncode?.setSelection(pos!!)
              }
              count = mBinding?.txtAbncode?.text.toString().length

          }

          override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int,
                                         count: Int, after: Int) {

          }

          override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int,
                                     before: Int, count: Int) {

          }
      })
```

count is 0 which is declared in top. But this solution works fine when I insert character. but when I remove characters till 2nd,6th and 10th characters and then resume typing then spaces addition doesn't work.

Please help me out this with some explanation. I have understood 'if' block which is adding spaces,but what 'else' is doing in that.My .xml file of edit text is

```
   <EditText
      android:id="@+id/txtAbncode"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:hint="51 824 753 553"
      android:maxLines="1"
      android:background="@null"
      android:inputType="number"
      android:maxLength="14"
      android:text="@{profileViewModel.profileModel.abnNumber}"
      android:textSize="@dimen/txt_normal"
      android:textColor="@android:color/white"
      android:textColorHint="#80FFFFFF"
      app:fontFamily="@font/sf_pro_text_bold"/>
```

Comment: Overriding the text change listener is a pretty good way of doing this. I don't think there is other way.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this way:-

```
 **YourEdittext**.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable?) {
                val inputLength = **YourEdittext**.text.toString().length
                if (count<=inputLength && (inputLength == 2 || inputLength == 6 || inputLength == 10)) {

**YourEdittext**.setText(YourEdittext.text.toString().plus(" "))
                val pos = **YourEdittext**.text?.length
                **YourEdittext**.setSelection(pos!!)
            }else if (count>=inputLength && (inputLength==3 || 
           inputLength==7 || inputLength==11)) {

                    YourEditext.setText(YourEditext.text!!.substring(0,YourEditext.text!!.length-1))
                    val pos = YourEditext.text?.length
                    YourEditext.setSelection(pos!!)
                }
            count=**YourEdittext**.text.toString().length

        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {

        }

        override fun onTextChanged(text: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
            Log.d("TEXTVALUE","="+**YourEdittext**.text.toString().replace(" ",""))
        }
    })
```

Comment: Actually It is working same as before. My problem is that when I am removing text till  2nd,6th and 10th characters and then resume typing then spaces addition doesn't work.For example suppose I typed 51 824 753 553 then removing last three digits 553 then if I resume typing then space addition doesn't work.